# Why `arima()` and `Arima()` give different AIC and sigma2 while giving the same coefficients and same likelihood?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

This problem occurred several times when I was trying to find the best parameters for ARIMA models in R. Here is an example:

My data is:

```
22 41 34 29 27 41 37 17 40 38 31 25 27 30 36 42 26 31 28 20 36 37 39 29 53 59 43 36 33 43 33 17 43 42 52 44 45 51 66 45 38 41 37 37 52 55 43 40 61 45 71 57 66 85 85 37 51 58 50 56 47 63 89 57 54 76 73 51 82 119 108 86
```

I read my data and transform it into ts object:

```
data <- read.table('test_data.txt')
data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
ts.test <- ts(data, start = c(2014, 1), frequency = 12)
```

I try to find the best parameters by using `auto.arima()` of an exogenous variable `tt`:

```
tt <- seq(length(ts.test))
auto.arima(ts.test, xreg = tt)
```

It gives the result as follow:

```
## Series: ts.test 
## Regression with ARIMA(0,0,1)(2,0,0)[12] errors 
## 
## Coefficients:
##          ma1    sar1    sar2  intercept    xreg
##       0.5386  0.2667  0.2558    21.7004  0.7458
## s.e.  0.0951  0.1298  0.1515     5.3415  0.1128
## 
## sigma^2 estimated as 132.9:  log likelihood=-277.4
## AIC=566.79   AICc=568.09   BIC=580.45
```

And when I try with `Arima()`:

```
Arima(ts.test, xreg = tt, order = c(0, 0, 1),
      seasonal = list(order = c(2, 0, 0), period = 12))
```

It gives the same results with `auto.arima()` in terms of $\sigma^2$ and the AIC as well as the likelihood:

```
## Series: ts.test 
## Regression with ARIMA(0,0,1)(2,0,0)[12] errors 

## Coefficients:
##          ma1    sar1    sar2  intercept    xreg
##       0.5386  0.2667  0.2558    21.7004  0.7458
## s.e.  0.0951  0.1298  0.1515     5.3415  0.1128
## 
## sigma^2 estimated as 132.9:  log likelihood=-277.4
## AIC=566.79   AICc=568.09   BIC=580.45
```

But when I try to fit it with `arima()`:

```
arima(ts.test, xreg = tt, order = c(0, 0, 1),
      seasonal = list(order = c(2, 0, 0), period = 12))
```

It gives me:

```
## Call:
## arima(x = ts.test, order = c(0, 0, 1), seasonal = list(order = c(2, 0, 0), period = 12), xreg = tt)
## 
## Coefficients:
##          ma1    sar1    sar2  intercept    xreg
##       0.5386  0.2667  0.2558    21.7004  0.7458
## s.e.  0.0951  0.1298  0.1515     5.3415  0.1128
## 
## sigma^2 estimated as 123.6:  log likelihood = -277.4,  aic = 564.79
```

Notice that the 3 functions give out the same parameters and their standard errors but the `arima()` gives different $\sigma^2$ and different AIC (always augmented by 2 than other AIC) while the likelihood stays the same.

Can anybody give an explanation? Thanks alot!

Comment: The AIC is a combination of a loglikelihood and a penalty term for the estimated parameters. How ' strong '  penalty term is a rather subjective matter.

Comment: It could be that the degrees of freedom used to calculate $\sigma^2$ is different in arima. I would check the arima code and see what is being used for that and  do the same thing for the Arima function. Since the coefficients are the same, I'm pretty certain that is causing the difference.  Of course, that means that one of the functions has a big but I'm not sure which one. Also, check if you get the same thing when you don't use xreg. It might be that the DOF are only incorrect when xreg is used.

Comment: @Nadia Merquez: Hi. The AIC can be different and not a problem since there are scale factors. So, you can compare AIC's as long as you're consistent ( with what you use for the scale factors ). But the $\hat\sigma^2$ shouldn't be different. That's not a scale factor issue.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: @mlofton When not using xreg, `Arima()` and `arima()` give still same parameters and different $\sigma^2$ and AIC. There is always a difference of 2 between the two AICs.

Comment: @Alain: OUYANG: Rob Hyndman's explanation hopefully clears it up for you.

Comment: @mlofton Yes, thank you very much as well!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`stats::arima()` estimates $\sigma^2$ using the MLE of the innovations variance, while `forecast::Arima()` uses the unbiased estimate $\sum e_i^2/(n-k)$ where $n$ is the number of observations available and $k$ is the number of parameters estimated.

`stats::arima()` does not count $\sigma^2$ as a parameter in the computation of the AIC, whereas `forecast::Arima()` does count it. [Burnham and Anderson (Springer, 2002)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387953649) recommend including $\sigma^2$ as per `Arima()`.

Comment: AIC = 2k - 2ln(L); k is the number of estimated parameters. `forecast::Arima()` will always have a k that is 1 greater than `stats::arima()` because it is counting \sigma^2 as a parameter that is estimated. The AIC from `stats::arima()` will always be exactly 2 units smaller than from `forecast::Arima()` because of this.

Comment: @iacobus wow, it seems that I didn't really understand the word **count**... Thank you very much, your explanation really helps!!!

Comment: @rob hyndman:  great explanation. thanks.